Типизация значений через дженерики
Я не знаю как правильнее описать то, что я имею ввиду.
Мне нужен такой интерфейс (в текущей реализации это не работает), но с тем дополнением, что я хочу добавить дополнительные значения для id, но в таком случае для value должен быть тип unknown
interface IColumn<T extends object, AdditionalKeys extends string = never, U = keyof (T & Record<AdditionalKeys, any>)>
{
  id: U;
  format(value: T[U]): any;
}

Ожидаемое поведение:
interface IColumn<T extends object, AdditionalKeys extends string = never, U = keyof (T & Record<AdditionalKeys, any>)>
{
  id: U;
  format(value: T[U]): any;
}

interface ITest
{
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
  key3: Date;
}

const columns: IColumn<ITest, "test">[] = [
  {
    id: "key1",
    format(value) // должен быть тип number
    {
      return value;
    }
  },
  {
    id: "key2",
    format(value) // должен быть тип string
    {
      return value;
    }
  },
  {
    id: "key3",
    format(value) // должен быть тип Date
    {
      return value;
    }
  },
  {
    id: "test",
    format(value) // должен быть тип unknown
    {
      return value;
    }
  },
  {
    id: "another", // Должна быть ошибка
    format(value)
    {
      return value;
    }
  }
]

TypeScript Playground

Types:
type IColumn<S extends Record<string, any>, ADD extends string = never> = ({
  [K in (keyof S) | ADD]: {
    id: K;
    format(value: K extends (keyof S) ? S[K] : unknown): any;
  };
})[(keyof S) | ADD];

interface ITest {
  key1: number;
  key2: string;
  key3: Date;
}

type TColumnsTest = IColumn<ITest, 'test'>[];

Result:
type TColumnsTest = ({
    id: "test";
    format(value: unknown): any;
} | {
    id: "key1";
    format(value: number): any;
} | {
    id: "key2";
    format(value: string): any;
} | {
    id: "key3";
    format(value: Date): any;
})[]

Usage example:
const columns = [
  ...
] as const satisfies TColumnsTest;


Завидую людям, которые понимают в таком :D Спасибо огромное, я уже весь гпт замучал и так не смог приблизится к нужному варианту.
Чудо блин)

Почему-то я не могу передать значение в format, пишет аругмент ... нельзя назначить параметру типа "never"

ну да, посмотрите на TColumnsTest, у вас каждый элемент массива может быть одинм из типов. это же union, а не turple. вам в сторону typeguard-ов или другой постановки задачи

@OliverPatterson попробуйте  as const satisfies TColumnsTest
